# Regex Getting around parentheses in a element

Tags: c#, regex

I have a question with regex, I'm trying to scrape a stock price. The element surrounding it looks like this:

```
<span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="52">17.89</span>
```

As you see there are multiple parentheses in that element so when I try to narrow it down with the following code the parentheses cause my script not to display any results.

```
MatchCollection list = Regex.Matches(data, "<span class=\"Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)\" (.+?)</span>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

I Know you can ignore quotation marks using \ but is there away to ignore parentheses?

Comment: you need to escape the parentheses, `Trsdu\(0.3s\)`, ect...

Comment: I tried that already it throws a unrecognized escape sequence when I try that

Comment: I'm so retarded its double //

Answer (score 0):

Double escape the parentheses solved it.